# NVD3.js bind hover/click events to the xAxis tick <line>

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3.js with [line and line-with-focus charts](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/examples.html) for a project. There is a requirement to bind data and events to the xAxis tick  elements. I've been trying in vain to bind events to a single line manually through the console.

```javascript
// try to bind to the first xAxis <line> in my line-with-focus chart
d3.select( 'div#problem-chart .nv-focus .nv-x .tick line' )
     .on( 'mouseover', function( e ){ 
                        console.log( e ); 
      } )
```

I've even set `chart.interactive( false )` to make sure there is no interactive layer that captures events and kills them. Has anyone managed to bind events to the xAxis or have guesses on why the above is not working?

Comment: Did you check if you're actually selecting something? It looks like your selector should be something like `div#problem-chart > .nv-focus > .nv-x > .tick > line`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: yes, i checked that. It is actually selecting something

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: it seems to be that sub elements of `g.nv-linesWrap` are capturing events and those events are not percolating to the `g.nv-focus` children. ugh

Comment: Hmm, I supposed you could select those elements and set `pointer-events: none` on them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to explicitly set the pointer-events property on the lines so they will respond to mouse events:

```
  d3.selectAll('g.nv-axis line')
    .style("pointer-events", "visiblePainted")
    .on("mouseover", function(){
      d3.select(this).style("stroke", "red");
    });
```

There's a CSS style rule turning off all pointer events on the axis components:

```
.nvd3 .nv-axis {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I had a heck of a time tracking it down, though -- the Chrome DOM inspector doesn't show it as an "inherited" style on the individual ticks even though it affects them.

Comment: P.S.  This works even with `.useInteractiveGuideline(true)` on a line chart, but some other types of interactives might still catch the mouse events.  E.g., it doesn't work on a "View Finder" graph, which has a brush selector layer grabbing all mouse events.